# JPA Hibernate, how to validate on create and ignore the validation on update

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bookings")
public class Booking {


    @Null
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Null
    @Column(name = "column1", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT 'CREATED'")
    private String column1;

    //the rest of the fields....
}
```

It is a simple spring boot project, the rule is no column1 data should be when creating a new row(therefore it uses the value '**CREATED**') however on the row update I like to change the value to '**ENDED**'

Is there a way to tell Hibernate to only do the validation when you create a new row and ignore the validation when you update it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

> @PrePersist   Executed before the entity manager persist operation is
>   actually executed or cascaded. This call is synchronous with the
>   persist operation.
>
> @PreUpdate    Executed before the database UPDATE operation.

```
      @PrePersist
      protected void onCreate() {
        column1 = "CREATED";
      }

      @PreUpdate
      protected void onUpdate() {
        column1 = "ENDED";
      }
```

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html